# How can I get URL parameters which have no value?

Tags: java, jsp, url-parameters

access using URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test.jsp?action=test&abc
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1/test.jsp?abc
```

how can I get the String "abc" ?

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<% java.util.Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
    while(names.hasMoreElements()){
        out.println(names.nextElement() + "<br>");
    }
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this.  Basically you need to iterate over the request's query parameter *names* and look for the parameter or parameters that don't have a value.  I suspect that you will need to resort to embedding a Java scriptlet, or writing your own Tag (in Java).

A better idea is to stick to "name=value" syntax in your URL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getQueryString();
```

returns the whole query string after the URL.